# Angular 2 reactive forms not triggering with custom input components

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having some trouble in making the validation work for my custom input components. I've successfully implemented the "ControlValueAccessor" interface to my component and it correctly populates the "FormGroup" object; yet, the validation doesn't trigger unless I do it manually. Here's the code:

**parent.component.html**

```
<form role="form" [formGroup]="loginForm" (submit)="login($event)" class="c-login__panel u-marg-30">
  ...
  <ika-text-input formControlName="username" label="USERNAME" [invalid]="username.invalid && (username.dirty || username.touched)"></ika-text-input>
  <div class="u-marg-30"></div>
  <ika-text-input formControlName="password" label="PASSWORD" type="password" [invalid]="password.invalid && (password.dirty || password.touched)"></ika-text-input>
  <a href="" [routerLink]="['/login/forgot-password']" class="txt--link txt-s--s txt-w--l col-primary">{{ 'FORGOT_PASSWORD_QUESTION' | translate }}</a>      <br>

  <button type="submit" class="o-btn o-btn--primary o-btn--big u-marg-30" [disabled]="loginForm.pristine || loginForm.invalid">{{ 'ENTER' | translate }}</button>
</div>
```

**parent.component**

```
get username() { return this.loginForm.get('username'); }
get password() { return this.loginForm.get('password'); }
...
this.loginForm = _formBuilder.group({
  username: [null, Validators.required],
  password: [null, Validators.required]
});
```

With this code, the "invalid" property of my custom input always stays to "false" whatever changes I do. My temporary solution being:

```
this.loginForm.valueChanges.subscribe((el) => {
  el.forEach((control) => {
    if (control instanceof FormControl) {
      el.markAsDirty();
    }
  });
});
```

I would definitely avoid using the above, but I really don't know why it isn't working. As said, only the validators aren't working.

**EDIT:**

The ika-text-input contains:

```
<div class="o-input-group o-input-group--{{size || 'big'}}">
 <input #inputElement [(ngModel)]="inputValue" [id]="formControlName" 
 [type]="type || 'text'" [class.is-error]="invalid" [type]="type || 'text'" 
 class="o-input-group__field" (change)="onChange(inputElement.value)" 
 (focus)="inputFocus($event)" (blur)="inputBlur($event)">
 <label #labelElement [for]="formControlName" class="o-input-group__label 
 js-animated-label" [class.is-error]="invalid">{{ label | translate }}
 </label>
</div>
```

Comment: You call `this.loginForm = _formBuilder.group({` in the constructor?

Comment: That's correct, I call it in the constructor of the component

Comment: Hmm... do you really want to have two child components? Just asking, I don't understand why you wouldn't just have one child component? :)

Comment: I don't think I understood your question I'm afraid. What you mean?

The structure is something like LoginComponent > CustomInputComponent.

Comment: I see you have two tags of `ika-text-input` in your code. Why not just pass the username and password as a nested group or the form to just one `ika-text-input`? Seems you are doing something I have never done with reactive forms, maybe I'm just not understanding the use case :)

Comment: I've added the content of ika-text-input in the main question. It's just commodity to avoid writing the whole input group everytime

Comment: Can you try to inject `ChangeDetecterRef` and do `_cdRef.detectChanges()`?

Comment: Would I inject it into the ika-input component or in the parent one? I suppose in the "ika-input".